# bmp file, access to data

Tags: c++, image-processing

this is a bmp file header:

```
    unsigned char header[54] = {
    0x42,        // identity : B
    0x4d,        // identity : M
    0, 0, 0, 0,  // file size
    0, 0,        // reserved1
    0, 0,        // reserved2
    54, 0, 0, 0, // RGB data offset
    40, 0, 0, 0, // struct BITMAPINFOHEADER size
    0, 0, 0, 0,  // bmp width
    0, 0, 0, 0,  // bmp height
    1, 0,        // planes
    24, 0,       // bit per pixel
    0, 0, 0, 0,  // compression
    0, 0, 0, 0,  // data size
    0, 0, 0, 0,  // h resolution
    0, 0, 0, 0,  // v resolution 
    0, 0, 0, 0,  // used colors
     0, 0, 0, 0   // important colors
  };
```

Now, how can i access data in a .bmp file and store them to an array?

Comment: Your header seems incomplete.  Most of the items are 0.  Where is the width and height?

Comment: This is **one** possible bitmap file header. For example, the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` can also be a `BITMAPV4HEADER` or a `BITMAPV5HEADER`. The bitmap file format is more complex than you think. Don't try to roll your own bitmap loader, and use what's already there: [`LoadImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045.aspx) or the [Windows Imaging Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx).

Comment: All constants you need are there. Bitmap data is at (drum roll) `RGB data offset` and is `data size` bytes long.

Comment: @Jongware The meaning of the data, however, is (drum roll) scattered all over the place. Data size can be zero as well.

Answer (score 0):

The bitmap header is a section in the file that holds information about the image and type of bitmap. If you want to read the individual pixels of a 24-bit bitmap file, you gather information about its size from the header, and then you use that to traverse the file and get your data.

From the header, you can clearly see that the pixel data starts at position 54 in the file. This is a 24-bit bitmap, so each pixel is represented by 3 bytes.

You also need to put padding into account. If the width of a bitmap is not divisible by 4, filler bytes are added to. ***+Correction: if the width * (bytes-per-pixel) is not divisible by 4.***

If you really want to see how a bitmap is structured and to make it easier to visualize when you code this, get a hex editor and create small bitmap files and open them in the hex editor. You can see how the bytes are arranged and where the header begins and ends, among other information.

Comment: Scanlines must be `DWORD` aligned. This does not imply, that the width must be a multiple of 4, but rather that `width * bytes_per_pixel` must be. There's lots and lots and lots more to take into account, though, like the compression, how to deal with a data size of 0, how to deal with a negative height, etc., etc., etc.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the correction. Also, most bitmaps aren't compressed and it's most likely that he's dealing with the typical 24bit uncompressed bitmap. It's also unlikely that he's going to build some kind of bitmap loader, but probably something to get an image into his program.

Comment: *"Something to get an image into a program"* **is** a bitmap loader. You may be able to skip some of the checks if you author the images yourself. With at least one major vendor of imaging tools that produces non-standard bitmaps this is still a non-trivial task.